# REPLACE not doing what I need in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, replace

I've got a query pulling data from a table.  In one particular field, there are several cases where it is a zero, but I need the four digit location number.  Here is where I'm running into a problem.  I've got

```
SELECT REPLACE(locationNbr, '0', '1035') AS LOCATION...
```

Two issues -

1. Whoever put the table together made all fields VARCHAR, hence the single quotes.
2. In the cases where there already is the number 1035, I get 1103535 as the location number because it's replacing the zero in the middle of 1035.

How do I select the locationNbr field and leave it alone if it's anything other than zero (as a VARCHAR), but if it is zero, change it to 1035?  Is there a way to somehow use TO_NUMBER within the REPLACE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN locationNbr='0' THEN '1035' ELSE locationNbr END AS LOCATION...
```

`REPLACE( string, string_to_replace , replacement_string )`

`REPLACE` looks for a `string_to_replace` inside a `string` and replaces it with a `replacent_string`. That is why you get the undesired behaviour - you are using the wrong function.

`CASE WHEN condition THEN result1 ELSE result2 END`
`CASE` checks a `condition` and if it is true it returns `result1` and if it is not it will return `result2`. This is a simple example, you can write a case statement with more than one condition check.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `replace()`.  Use `case`:

```
(case when locationNbr = '0' then '1035' else locationNbr end)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of length in Oracle:

```
select case when length(loacation) = 1 then REPLACE(loacation, '0', '1035') else loacation end as location
from location_test;
```